# Gravity Form + Stripe plugin giving credit card error

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, stripe-payments, gravity-forms-plugin

I am working with the gravity forms plugin. All the other forms are working fine but in one whenever I enter the credit card details and submit it gives me the following error:

> Your card was declined. Your request was in live mode, but used a known test card.

After searching the web, the most commonsolution I found is that to test it in "Test Mode". I have checked it is in Test Mode as well but it's not allowing me to submit the form.

Comment: So when stripe plugin is in test mode and you enter the test cardnumber what error do you get?

Comment: "This form cannot process subscription payments. Please contact site owner" i am having this error now when i have shifted it to Test Mode

Comment: Hmm.. I think this has something to do with the stripe plugin not supporting subscription type payments.. maybe submit your question to the creator of stripe plugin (automattic I think)

Comment: i have further explored it the plugin has some issue with the Stripe Setting-> Rule when i disable the rule forms submits successfully.can u tell what is the purpose of stripe rule?

Comment: Rule? Are you using woocommerce or wordpress stripe plugin?

Comment: i am using sordpress stripe plugin but in it after creating a form u have to add rule for it or u can say it a "stripe feed" i have problem with that "stripe feed" when i disable it the form submits successfully.